# Faster Code Anyone? :)

Tags: c, performance, algorithm

EDIT:  shaved roughly 10% processing time with:

```
register int16_t *libwordPointer = libword;
int16_t *nReset;
register int16_t *wordsPointer = words[word];
int16_t *mReset = wordsPointer;

for( int n=0 ; n<Rows ; n++ ){  
    nReset = libwordPointer;
    wordsPointer = mReset;
    for( int m=0 ; m<Col ; m++ ){
        temp = 0;
        libwordPointer = nReset;
        for( int ii=0 ; ii<Q ; ii++ ){
            temp += lookUp( abs( *libwordPointer - *wordsPointer ) );
            libwordPointer++;
            wordsPointer++;
        }
        D[n][m] = temp;
    }
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Any expert opinions on how to make this faster????  Award is a million dollars :)

```
 float dtw( int16_t (*words)[L][Q], int16_t (*libword)[Q], int16_t libcount, char word ){


    float Dist, k=0;
//  int Dn;
    register int Rows = libcount;   
    register float A, B, C; 
    register float temp;    
    register int Col = ender[word]-begin[word]+1;   // rows for word being tested

    for( int n=0 ; n<Rows ; n++ ){      
        for( int m=0 ; m<Col ; m++ ){
            temp = 0;
            for( int ii=0 ; ii<Q ; ii++ ){
                temp += lookUp(abs(libword[n][ii]-words[word][m][ii]));
            }
            D[n][m] = temp; 
        }
    }

    for( int n=1 ; n<Rows ; n++ ){                      
        D[n][0] += D[n-1][0];
    }
    for( int m=1 ; m<Col ; m++ ){
        D[0][m] += D[0][m-1];
    }
    for( int n=1 ; n<Rows ; n++ ){
        for( int m=1 ; m<Col ; m++ ){
            D[n][m] += mininum1( D[n-1][m], D[n-1][m-1], D[n][m-1] );
        }
    }

    Dist=D[Rows-1][Col-1];                          // minimum distance to end
    register int n=Rows-1;                          // now work backwards
    register int m=Col-1;
    k=1;
    while( (n+m) != 0 ){
        if( n == 0 ){
            m--;
        }else if( m == 0 ){
            n--;
        }else{
            A=D[n-1][m];
            B=D[n][m-1];
            C=D[n-1][m-1];
            if( A < B ){
                if( A < C ){
                    n--;
                }else{
                    n--;
                    m--;
                }
            }else if( B < C ){
                m--;
            }else{
                n--;
                m--;
            }

        }
        k++;
    }

    return Dist/k;
}
```

where lookup is this:

```
float lookUp(int16_t pow){

    if( pow < MAX_DIFFERENCE ){
        return powLookup[pow];

    }else{
        return MAX_DIFFERENCE_POW;
    }

}
```

and powLookup is this:

```
const float powLookup[MAX_DIFFERENCE]={
    0,
    1,
    4,
    9,
    16,
    25,
    36,
    49,
    64,
    81,
    100,
    121,
    144,
    169,
    196,
    225,
    256,
```

... and on

The idea is to make it more efficient in terms of micro instruction.  You can see I have tried to make it better with a power lookup but it is still killer in processing.  Any ideas are welcome.  Maybe a faster way of indexing arrays?

Comment: "I hereby declare Nik Bougalis $500,000 before attempting to condense my code, and another $500,000 when he has successfully impressed me." :)

Comment: Too vague. Also not legally binding.

Comment: Did you minus my post?  Duddeee com on broski

Comment: fastest way is just to make the first line of function dtw: return false

Comment: Multiplying an integer by itself is actually significantly faster than  your lookup function...

Comment: @Arthur the lookup function is likely useful for the inverse: find the lowerbound of a value x: the index is the integer square root

Comment: Alright everyone is being a harsh critic here, I will have to defend myself.  Arthur I am sorry bud but my 20,000 scope probing test points says you couldn't be further from the truth.

Comment: Any chance we're talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping ?

Comment: @user2368363 Actually, everyone is being mild. I'd have [voted to close as NARQ/Not constructive in a second](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv). Your question is entirely unrealistic. And 10 psychic reading points tell me you are aware of that. So, unless you tell us _what_ the application domain is, and what the function is helping achieve, we can't even begin to interpret the existing code, let alone come up with realistic improvements. Have a good day.

Comment: Have a good day?  I am assuming you're still there.  I was merely asking to see if anybody could point out simple operations that could be faster (ex: user2368363, you seem to pass an array into your function lookup. . .  maybe it would be faster to change your 2-d arrays to 1-d arrays and keep a pointer to single index for what address the new address is.  That could probably be 10x faster)

Comment: @user2368363 your scope probing test points are irrelevant if you implement it wrong. Sure thing calling abs unnecessarily and casting int to float at each iteration would slow down the multiplication.

Comment: @user2368363 I was assuming you understood _some_ of the code yourself. Because, if you did, you'd recognize from the use of the `register` keywords alone that this thing is supposed to be pretty much optimized to death already. So either way, asking for "free" optimization advice on SO seems gratuitous (if you _didn't_ understand that much I'd say you shouldn't meddle with this code. You could hire someone to do the work for you). My $0.02: lose the `register` keywords, compile in C++ mode with `-std=c++11 -march=native -O3`. Perhaps mark a few things `const` if possible. Good luck

Comment: Thanks not-sehe, definitely wasn't trying to offend you.  It seems as though everyone hates me on this post so I must have done something wrong as you said.  As far as the const goes, check out the lookup table again, as far as understanding the code I wrote every word, as far as the type registers they only help to an extent especially when I have 3 interrupts running in the background.  This will prolly be my last post on this cite for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lookuptable for just (n*n) in the inner loop hurts (multiplication is not expensive on most architectures. Function calls are). You could at least replace it by a inline function, or a macro like:

```
static inline float lookUp(int16_t num)
{
return (num >= MAX_DIFFERENCE) ? MAX_DIFFERENCE_POW : num*num;
}
```

Macro version:

```
#define lookUp(n) (((n) >=MAX_DIFFERENCE) ? MAX_DIFFERENCE_POW : (n)*(n))
```

The macro version should of course not be used if there are side-effects in its arguments, since it evaluates more than once.

Comment: Yea the thing is that the multiplication happens roughly 64*64*15 times (61440 times) and when I clocked it both ways, the lookup was way faster.  But I do like your suggestions with the inline! Thanks!

Comment: Hey Joop!  So I put in your macro version, great idea by the way, and I was wondering what you meant by side effects???  Thanks!

Comment: Side effects would be if you called the macro like `val = lookUp(i++);` (or via a function with side effects, such as getc())

Answer (score 0):

You've got a triply-nested loop, and in the innermost loop, you're doing a triple-index and using a function call with table lookup just to square a number.

Engage your brain and do that more intelligently.

Comment: Yea it looks ugly, thanks for contributing!  I retried with this:

Comment: please see above for edit . . .

Comment: keep in mind some things are hard to change because the size of row and col are dynamic along with the words that come in

Comment: @user2368363: what the matter with `int temp1 = abs( *libwordPointer - *wordsPointer ); temp += temp1*temp1;`   ?

Comment: It is slower. I am doing it 60,000 times each time I enter.

Comment: @user2368363: Number of times doesn't matter. What matters is percent of time. You're telling me a table lookup is faster than an integer multiply? What kind of machine is this, anyway?

Comment: number of times multiplies the effect of % of time to the point where a small change is amplified into a big one.  And yes it is, think in terms of micro instructions for a "hey, ur answer is at this address" versus "hey do all this math".  Looking at it in terms of assembly is misleading, look at in terms of micro instructions.  Hardware is avr32 bit UC3.

Comment: @user2368363: Count does not multiply the %. The % is the result of multiplying the routine's time, times the count, divided by the total execution time. The % is the fraction of total time that routine is responsible for. Now, as I look [*here*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVR32) it says that chip has an accumulate-multiply unit (as well as an FPU), so it should be able to multiply two integers in 1 or 2 processor cycles.

Answer (score 0):

These are tricks - which might not make your code more maintainable , but ...

Little trick, might give you a few percent:
Instead of counting up in for(...) loops, count down to 0.  Many CPUs create tighter code with a test of 0 rather than N.  Also if you *know* the first pass through the loop *must* happen, use a do ... while loop

```
for( int ii=0 ; ii<Q ; ii++ ){
```

change to

```
int ii=Q;
do {
  ...
} while (ii-- > 0);
```

2nd trick (only helps a little)
This loop re-looksup "D[n][m-1]".  As you are running down the list, same the D[n][m] for the next loops "D[n][m-1]";

```
for( int m=1 ; m<Col ; m++ ){
  D[n][m] += mininum1( D[n-1][m], D[n-1][m-1], D[n][m-1] );
```

to
    float Dprevious = D[n][1] += mininum1( D[n-1][1], D[n-1][1-1], D[n][1-1] );
    for( int m=2 ; m

You could do this in your "while( (n+m) != 0 ){" loop too.

3rd idea: Big trick: I *assume* your floating point must be expensive, else, why the lookUp()? So instead of doing any floating point math (except maybe that last "Dist/k") use integer math throughout.  It look like you could get by with it.

Cheers!